# How to set deployment target to 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Can I change the deployment target to 5.0.1 and not 5.0 or 5.1 . Xcode only shows 5.0 and 5.1. I need this to make my app compatible with apple's data storage guidelines. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** change your deployment target to that version of iOS (5.0.1). The deployment target is different. The deployment target is a flag saying which is the oldest version of the OS that's supported.